# Core Text / NSStringDrawing - CFAttributedStringRef / NSAttributedString - changing font size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-text

Case: The attributed string is already created. How can the size of the string be altered?

I'm guessing we could either

A) Update pointSize for all fonts in the attributed string

B) Draw the attributed string with some transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine on both Mac OS and iOS

```
@implementation NSAttributedString (Scale)

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringWithScale:(double)scale
{
    if(scale == 1.0)
    {
        return self;
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *copy = [self mutableCopy];
    [copy beginEditing];

    NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, copy.length);

    [self enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:fullRange options:0 usingBlock:^(UIFont *oldFont, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        double currentFontSize = oldFont.pointSize;
        double newFontSize = currentFontSize * scale;

        // don't trust -[UIFont fontWithSize:]
        UIFont *scaledFont = [UIFont fontWithName:oldFont.fontName size:newFontSize];

        [copy removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
        [copy addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:scaledFont range:range];
    }];

    [self enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:fullRange options:0 usingBlock:^(NSParagraphStyle *oldParagraphStyle, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *newParagraphStyle = [oldParagraphStyle mutableCopy];
        newParagraphStyle.lineSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.headIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.tailIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.minimumLineHeight *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.maximumLineHeight *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore *= scale;

        [copy removeAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:range];
        [copy addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:newParagraphStyle range:range];
    }];

    [copy endEditing];
    return copy;
}

@end
```

Happy coding

Comment: "This works fine on both Mac OS and iOS" Is UIFont available in OS X?

Comment: Also, what's the issue with `-[UIFont fontWithSize:]`?

Comment: Right, just replace with NSFont. I don't recall at the moment what the issue was excactly, but I think it tried to be smart in a very buggy way. If I recall correctly I got the wrong font family! Pretty shocking. I wrote about it somewhere, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Okay, so I couldn't find it among my notes, but turns out others ran in to the same problem. see https://github.com/djibouti33/UIFontBug/blob/master/htmlLabelTest/ViewController.m and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041318/fontwithsize-returning-different-font-object

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down! It's helpful to have a link to the explanation here.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working with the following code. One miss though is if some text in the attributedstring has not been set a font-attribute it will not be updated. So i had to encapsulate everything with font-attributes.

```
- (void)recalculateSizeChangeInAttributedString {

    if(self.attributedStringOriginal == nil) {
        self.attributedStringOriginal = [self.attributedString copy];
    }

    CFMutableAttributedStringRef tempString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutableCopy(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), self.attributedStringOriginal.length, (CFMutableAttributedStringRef)self.attributedStringOriginal);

    int lastIndex = 0;
    int limit = CFAttributedStringGetLength(tempString);
    for (int index = 0; index < limit;) {

        CFRange inRange = CFRangeMake(0, limit - index);
        CFRange longestEffective;
        CTFontRef font = (CTFontRef)CFAttributedStringGetAttribute(tempString, index, kCTFontAttributeName, &longestEffective);

        if(font != nil) {

            // log for testing
            NSLog(@"index: %i, range: %i - %i, longest: %i - %i, attribute: %@", 
                  index, inRange.location, 
                  inRange.location + inRange.length, 
                  longestEffective.location, longestEffective.location + longestEffective.length, 
                  @"..." 
                  );


            // alter the font and set the altered font/attribute
            int rangeEnd = longestEffective.length != 0 ? longestEffective.length : 1;
            CTFontRef modifiedFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithAttributes(font, CTFontGetSize((CTFontRef)font) * sizeFactor, NULL, NULL); 
            CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(tempString, CFRangeMake(index, rangeEnd), kCTFontAttributeName, modifiedFont); 
            CFRelease(modifiedFont);

        }

        // make next loop continue where current attribute ended
        index += longestEffective.length; 

        if(index == lastIndex)
            index ++;
        lastIndex = index;

    }

    self.attributedString = (NSMutableAttributedString *)tempString;

    CFRelease(tempString); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe parsing is the only way. Attributed string can have quite complex format, it's your job to increase the font size.

However, if you need this trick for rendering, you can avoid string parsing - use a scale transform to increase the text size.

Comment: I'm not really sure where is best to implement CGAffineTransformMakeScale(). I tried doing it in drawrect, but then it was just applied to the all the glyphs which where weird since they had the same position.

Comment: Also, i would really much like to know dimensions, text left etc before actually drawing takes place.

Comment: hi again. please have a look at my try. Am I missing something or is there something i should take into consideration when doing it like that?

Comment: I think you can use default system font (and font size) as a basement for those formatted segments without the font attribute. Just a trick.